# OpenGL ES 1.0 - Incorrect rendering

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am loading .obj file and render it in android emulator. Although 3rd-party .obj viewers show model correctly (open3mod), when I launch it on android emulator it looks strange. Could you please explain why in enulator model reders incorrectly?

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer
{
    private Context context;
    private Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Float>> obj;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
        setRenderer(this);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config)
    {
        obj = new Hashtable<String, ArrayList<Float>>();

        try
        {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
              new InputStreamReader(context.getAssets().open("calculator.obj")));

            ArrayList<Float> vertex = new ArrayList<Float>();

            String name = null;
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.startsWith("v "))
                {
                    String[] parts = line.substring(2).trim().split("\\s+");

                    vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[0]).floatValue() / 2f)); // scale to smaller twice
                    vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[1]).floatValue() / 2f)); // scale to smaller twice
                    vertex.add(Float.valueOf(Float.valueOf(parts[2]).floatValue() / 2f)); // scale to smaller twice
                }

                if (line.startsWith("f "))
                {
                    String[] parts = line.substring(2).trim().split("\\s+");

                    obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[0]).intValue() - 1));
                    obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[1]).intValue() - 1));
                    obj.get(name).add(vertex.get(Integer.valueOf(parts[2]).intValue() - 1));
                }

                if (line.startsWith("g "))
                {
                    name = line.substring(2).trim();

                    obj.put(name, new ArrayList<Float>());
               }
            }

            reader.close();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height)
    {
        gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl)
    {
        gl.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);

        int i;

        ByteBuffer fByteBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(obj.get("calculator").size() * 4);
        fByteBuffer.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        FloatBuffer faces = fByteBuffer.asFloatBuffer();
        for (i = 0; i < obj.get("calculator").size(); i++)
          faces.put(obj.get("calculator").get(i).floatValue());            
        faces.position(0);

        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, faces);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLES, 0, faces.capacity() / 3);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to try a simpler OBJ file, and include both the obj file and the float list you are passing in to the API in your question. It's kinda hard to see where things are going,

Comment: problem is that float list also rendered incorrectly. i wrote obj2java script and imported it into main class - result is the same

Comment: Sure, which probably means you not reading the file correctly, but without seeing both the file, and what your script does with it, it is hard to tell ...

Answer (score 0):

Obj files are an indexed geometry format (that's what the face element lines start with "f " are encoding  - they tell you which vertices in the vertex array make up each triangle).

Your current code is decoding the index values, but totally ignores them when it comes to rendering. You need to use `glDrawElements`, using the index buffer to pick which vertices contribute to which triangles.

*EDIT* I missed the fact that you manually repack the vertex data on load. You don't need to do that - the API supports the indexed rendering natively (and it is much more efficient as shared verts are only processed once).

Comment: I have tried `glDrawElements` - the same result, because .obj file does not contain indices info and I am forced to index triangles simply from 0 to count of  vertices.

Comment: `you manually repack the vertex data on load` - please clearify.

Comment: "... because .obj file does not contain indices info". Yes they do. What do you think the lines beginning with "f " are? You already decode them and use them as indices ...

Comment: I t look indices from "f'" as you adviced and result is the same